# stop javascript countdown timer with onclick event

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

i need help, i make a javascript function for countdown timer with progress bar, here is code

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html('');
        $('#time_wrap').html('<span id="timer">'+timeleft+'</span>');
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }else{
            setTimeout(function() {
            submitdata();
        }, 1000);
        }
    };
```

i need to stop timer with onclick event, ex: `<input type="button" onclick="stoptimer();">`

how to stop the timer with function stoptimer() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp).

You can modify your code to be like:

```
var timer = null;

function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html('');
        $('#time_wrap').html('<span id="timer">'+timeleft+'</span>');
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    } else{
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            submitdata();
        }, 1000);
    }

    // You can use this to bind event only after the timer is set.
    // $('#stop-btn').on('click', function() { 
    //    clearTimeout(timer);
    // });
};

function stoptimer() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```